# My UI code doesn't show anything in emulator

Tags: android, interface, screen

I'm starting out in android development and I grabbed a sample code snippet from a book for a few text fields on an interface. I checked over and over that my code is identical to that in the book, but every time I compile and run, I get nothing but a black screen in the emulator.

Here's my code:

```
package me.kevinossia.mystuff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private LinearLayout nameContainer;
    private LinearLayout addressContainer;
    private LinearLayout parentContainer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        createNameContainer();
        createAddressContainer();
        createParentContainer();
        setContentView(parentContainer);
    }

    private void createNameContainer()
    {
        nameContainer = new LinearLayout(this);

        nameContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        nameContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView nameLbl = new TextView(this);

        nameLbl.setText("Name: ");
        nameContainer.addView(nameLbl);

        TextView nameValueLbl = new TextView(this);
        nameValueLbl.setText("Kevin");

        nameContainer.addView(nameValueLbl);
    }

    private void createAddressContainer()
    {
        addressContainer = new LinearLayout(this);

        addressContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        addressContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView nameLbl = new TextView(this);

        nameLbl.setText("Address: ");
        addressContainer.addView(nameLbl);

        TextView nameValueLbl = new TextView(this);

        nameValueLbl.setText("26662");
        addressContainer.addView(nameValueLbl);
    }

    private void createParentContainer()
    {
        parentContainer = new LinearLayout(this);

        parentContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        parentContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        parentContainer.addView(nameContainer);
        parentContainer.addView(addressContainer);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Here's my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.kevinossia.mystuff.tutorial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the new manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.kevinossia.mystuff.tutorial"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="me.kevinossia.mystuff.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

Comment: I would start by buying a book that teaches you to code the `layout` in xml because more than likely that's how you will do 98% of your `layout`. Other than that, try posting your `manifest` maybe

Comment: I actually probably should've said this: I also did the identical layout in an xml file as well, but I don't know what to do from there. Do I just click "Run"?

Comment: Yes, click Run. What are you doing if you aren't clicking run or debug? Also, I would suggest getting a real device to test on as soon as you can.

Comment: When I click Run and the emulator starts, there is only a black screen.

Comment: It works for me. Post your manifest. Is there any errors in the logcat? Also, do you have a real device you can test on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what the logcat is....and there is a device available for me to test it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything as your launcher in your `manifest`. You should have something like

```
  <application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="me.kevinossia.mystuff.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

inside the `<application>` tag. These are the important lines for that.

```
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

depending on your app

[manifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

[intent-filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: I added both of those and it still just shows a black screen.

Comment: You added the whole `<activity`> tag with the <intent-filter>` inside it?

Comment: Yes. I tried running the xml itself and the .java source file. Both just showed a black screen.

Comment: You really can only run a java file...you can't run an xml file. Post your update `manifest` below the old one. Are you testing on a real device now? If not, try to

Comment: How exactly do I test it on a real device?

Comment: Ok I tested it on my dad's phone and it worked. I'm guessing that it works on the emulator and that I just can't see it because the font's black. Problem solved!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. You may accept if you want because it wouldn't have launched without adjusting the `manifest`. Anyway, it is always better to test on a real device because it is faster and you normally get more predictable results